# как экранировать $ в EOF

Tags: bash

```
WP_CONF=$(cat <<EOF
<?php

$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

EOF
)


echo "${WP_CONF}"
```

Comment: Что бы записать многострочный текст в переменную , а потом создать файл и записать туда текст , по ssh

Comment: Стандартно, через `\ `.

Comment: Если интерполяция совсем не нужно, то можно EOF в одинарных кавычках указать. `<<'EOF'`

Comment: При обработке переменной потребуется экранирование экрана, т.е. поставить \\\, экранирует доллар, экранирует экран. Но проще создать файл с нужным содержимым у себя и скопировать его на другой сервере по средствам scp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте либо одночные кавычки, либо экранируйте с помощью обратной косой черты:

```
WP_CONF=$(cat <<EOF
<?php

\$table_prefix  = 'wp_';

EOF
)

echo "${WP_CONF}"
```

Или

```
WP_CONF='<?php

$table_prefix  = '"'"'wp_'"'"';'

echo "${WP_CONF}"
```

См. [пример работы скрипта онлайн](https://ideone.com/Y0ppHh) (и [второй пример](https://ideone.com/9Wmadf)).